# Http.GetFromJsonAsync ignores DataMember Attribute

Tags: c#, .net, json-deserialization, system.text.json

Let's take the blazor default template to retrieve forecast

```
forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("sample-data/weather.json")
```

But I want to map my Forecast class like that :

```
[DataContract]
public class WeatherForecast
{
    [DataMember(Name = "myDate", Order = 1)]
    public DateOnly Date { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "temperatureC", Order = 1)]
    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "summary", Order = 1)]
    public string? Summary { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
}
```

Json file has the following values

```json
  [
    {
      "myDate": "2023-01-06",
      "temperatureC": 1,
      "summary": "Freezing"
    },
    {
      "myDate": "2022-01-07",
      "temperatureC": 14,
      "summary": "Bracing"
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-08",
      "temperatureC": -13,
      "summary": "Freezing"
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-09",
      "temperatureC": -16,
      "summary": "Balmy"
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-10",
      "temperatureC": -2,
      "summary": "Chilly"
    }
  ]
```

Unfortunately, the 2 properties "myDate" are not retrieved when deserializing.

I really want to manage property names if for example if a have a c# property called `MyVeryLongNameProperty`, in the json I only want `MyProp` to reduce file size

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`GetFromJsonAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.getfromjsonasync?view=net-7.0#system-net-http-json-httpclientjsonextensions-getfromjsonasync-1(system-net-http-httpclient-system-string-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) uses `System.Text.Json` which [does not support data contracts](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29975#issuecomment-504610564) at the moment (and at the moment there are no plans too implement this support AFAIK). Use [`JsonPropertyNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=net-7.0):

```cs
public class WeatherForecast
{
    [JsonPropertyName("myDate")]
    public DateOnly Date { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("temperatureC")]
    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("summary")]
    public string? Summary { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
}
```